# HTML content overflowing outside CSS height

Tags: html, css

This is an image of the "overflow" problem on my webpage for a school assignment:
[image]

The worst quick-and-dirty solution would be just to extend the height x2 or something. But im woundering if there is a CSS way that automatically extends my div='body' height according to the amount of html content, but I'm doubtful such functionality exists.

*index.html*:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
<title>Project</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">
        <div id="loggeduser"><?php echo $usernamedisplayed; ?></div>
        <div id="loggedoutuser"><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>   </div>
    <div id="menu">
        <div id="homelink"><div id="currentlink"><a href="index.php">Home</a></div></div>
        <div id="loginlink"><a href="login.php">Login</a></div>
        <div id="signuplink"><a href="signup.php">Register</a></div>
        <div id="postinglink"><a href="post.php">Post</a></div>
        <div id="repostinglink"><a href="repost.php">Repost</a></div>
        <div id="userlink"><a href="user.php">User</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="body">
        <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Contents</th>
            <th>Date(D/M/Y)</th>
            <th>Image</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- ...a lot of PHP tables--> 

    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright © 2013, CS215 University of Regina. All rights reserved.</p>
        <a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer"> <img src="http://www.w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml11" alt="Valid XHTML 1.1 " height="31" width="88"/> </a>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
```

*style.css*:

```
/* Structure */

#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width:800px;
    height:1000px;
    font-size:1.20em;

}

#header {
    position: relative;
    height:200px;
    background:url(images/bubblerheader.png);
}

#menu {
    position: relative;
    height:40px;
    background:url(images/bubblermenu.png);
}

#body {
    position: relative;
    height:660px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}

#footer {
    position: relative;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
    background:url(images/bubblerfooter.png) no-repeat;
}

/* Structure Extras */

//a lot of id's and classes
```

Comment: You are using `height:660px;` for `body`, you shouldn't use it...

Answer (score 1):

CSS has the ability to automatically adjust the height of elements to fill their content.

Try the following:

```
#body
{
    position: relative;
    height:auto;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}
```

Comment: `height: auto;` is default, OP have to get rid of the fixed `height`, no need to define `auto`

Comment: Very true! As long as he ensures height is never set anywhere else that may override the default

Answer (score 0):

I think that needs to happen in the wrapper.

```
    #wrapper {
    height: auto;}
```

You can also do this:

```
    #wrapper {
    overflow-y: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this css

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width:800px;
    height:auto;
    font-size:1.20em;

}
```

BODY

```
#body {
    position: relative;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to have the body's height to be `660px` as a starting point, you can change `height` to `min-height`.

```
#body {
    position: relative;
    min-height:660px;
    background-color:#00CCCC;
}
```

If you don't care about the height of the body you can just leave out `height` from the body css because it will scale depending on its contents.

Lastly, remove the `height` in the wrapper unless you're sure that your entire page won't go that far down.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width:800px;
    font-size:1.20em;
}
```

If you want to keep the height to `1000px` you can add `overflow-y: auto` to the wrapper so it shows a scrollbar just in case the contents go over.

```
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    width:800px;
    height:1000px;
    font-size:1.20em;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```